# Symfony pure html form

Tags: php, html, symfony

I want to create a form in symfony php template 
eg: 
`
    Hotel Name

```
<label>Hotel address</label>
<input type="text" name="">
```

`

I do not want use form objects for creation and also do not want anything other than this(pure handcoded form ) in my php view and in controller action i want to access this data

help me !!

Comment: then just use forms. What's the problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use forms? That is what they are for.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the form in your view.

```
<form action="<route>" class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top:20px;
  padding-left:    40px;">
  <label>Hotel Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="_name">
  <label>Hotel address</label>
  <input type="text" name="_address">
  <input type="submit"  />
  </form>`
```

then get the values in Controller action

```
$name = $request->get('_name');
$address = $request->get('_address');
```

Comment: how to access those values in symfony controller

Comment: with `Request` object

Comment: @ShridharUPatil Accept the answer please.